# Cast jsondata to NameValueCollection

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms

I trying to pass JSON from jQuery to .ASHX file.
I want  retrieve JSON data in  .ASHX file by HttpContext and cats to NameValueCollection.
How do it?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GetLetterInformationHandler.ashx",
    data: "{'Name':'david', 'Family':'logan'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "Get",
    datatype: "json",
    onSuccess: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Now I can use the querystring and And cast as follows:

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        string cururl = context.Request.Url.ToString();
        int iqs = context.Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf('?');
        string querystring = (iqs < cururl.Length - 1) ? cururl.Substring(iqs + 1) : String.Empty;
        NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    }
```

I want use json insted of querystring

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.map(data.d, function (item) {
    return {
       name: item.Name,
       family: item.Family
    };
})
```

Or if you want each function:

```
var resultData = data.d;
$.each(resultData, function() {
    alert(this)
})
```

Comment: I use dynamic parameters.Also other parts of the application sent parameters to ashx

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes hope this will help you :)

**Ajax function**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "GetLetterInformationHandler.ashx",
  data: "{'Name':'david', 'Family':'logan'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
               if( data != null){
                  if (data.msg == "SUCCESS"); {
                      alert( data.msg)
                  }
               }
           },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert(textStatus);
         }
  });
```

**.ASHX file**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
{     
   string outputToReturn = String.Empty;   // Set it to Empty Instead of  ""        
   context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";     

   var getName = String.Empty ;     
   var getFamily = String.Empty ;      // Make sure if the Particular Object is Empty or not
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["Name"]))         
     {           
        getName = context.Request["Name"];         
     }

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["Subject"]))        
     {             
        getFamily = context.Request["Subject"];         
     }

    NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
    nvc.Add(getName, getFamily);
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
    {
        dict.Add(key, nvc[key]);
    }
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dict);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Comment: I edit my question to clarify the issue.Your sample is static parameters

Comment: @ZSH i have made some changes!! i hope it will help you